# vertical flicker on a div that expands horizontally with content in it using css

Tags: css, menu, hover, css-transitions

Hey there all:) I'm going blind with an issue that evolves around a little flicker effect that comes when I hover my menu item "Design". It should only show the content horizontally.

If anyone could point something out in my code or give some tips / help on my problem I would be really happy! Online example: http://instagib.dk/westring-kbh/#

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}
/******* Menu ********/

.menu {
  float: right;
}
.menu_item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
}
.menu_item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.menu_item:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
.menu_item:hover .menu_expand_item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 70px;
}
.menu_item .menu_expand_item {
  display: none;
}
/******* Social share in menu ********/

.social_expand {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  right: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #303F4A;
}
.social_expand:hover {
  width: 110px;
}
.social_share {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.social_expand:hover .social_share {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 18px;
}
.facebook {
  background: url(../img/facebook_icon.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.twitter {
  background: url(../img/twitter_icon.png) no-repeat center center;
}
/************ Header DRY declerations *********/

.header,
.logo:hover {
  background-color: #2A3238;
}
.logo,
.social_expand:hover,
.menu_item:hover {
  background-color: #303F4B;
}
.twitter,
.facebook {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
}
.menu_item,
.menu_item:hover,
.social_expand,
.social_expand:hover {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo-icon.png" alt="Westring-kbh logo" width="70" height="70">
  </a>

  <div class="social_expand">
    <div class="twitter">
      <p class="social_share">Del os</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="social_expand">
    <div class="facebook">
      <p class="social_share">Del os</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu_item">
      <a href="#">Design</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Dick</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Dick</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Dick</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      <a href="#">Websites</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      <a href="#">Seo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Not sure if I got your issue right. Add `height: 70px` to `.menu_item` and the issue of the div starting from below is fixed.

Comment: This worked:) Thx so much. Was getting tired in my eyes looking for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it flickers is because once on hover, it moves down of the navbar... The reason for it is because it expends in width, and becomes wider than the space available because of the picture... So it goes on another line... See it in action by using your browser debugger and toggling hover on and off. Or use this snippet, which is the same as yours, with a HOVER class so you can see.

```css
.header {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  height: 70px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.logo {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  float: left;
}
/******* Menu ********/

.menu {
  float: right;
}
.menu_item {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 110px;
  border:1px solid black;
}
.menu_item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  width: 110px;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
.menu_item:hover,.menu_item.hover  {
  width: 300px;
}
.menu_item:hover .menu_expand_item ,.menu_item.hover .menu_expand_item {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 40px;
  height: 70px;
}
.menu_item .menu_expand_item {
  display: none;
}
/******* Social share in menu ********/

.social_expand {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
  right: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  border-left: 1px solid #303F4A;
}
.social_expand:hover {
  width: 110px;
}
.social_share {
  position: absolute;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  height: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.social_expand:hover .social_share {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 18px;
}
.facebook {
  background: url(../img/facebook_icon.png) no-repeat center center;
}
.twitter {
  background: url(../img/twitter_icon.png) no-repeat center center;
}
/************ Header DRY declerations *********/

.header,
.logo:hover {
  background-color: #2A3238;
}
.logo,
.social_expand:hover,
.menu_item:hover {
  background-color: #303F4B;
}
.twitter,
.facebook {
  float: left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 70px;
}
.menu_item,
.menu_item:hover,
.menu_item.hover,
.social_expand,
.social_expand:hover {
  -webkit-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
  transition: width 0.1s, linear 0.1s;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="logo">
    <img src="img/logo-icon.png" alt="Westring-kbh logo" width="70" height="70">
  </a>

  <div class="social_expand">
    <div class="twitter">
      <p class="social_share">Del os</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="social_expand">
    <div class="facebook">
      <p class="social_share">Del os</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu_item hover">
      <a href="#">Design</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Dick</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Dick</a>
      <a href="#" class="menu_expand_item">Dick</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      <a href="#">Websites</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      <a href="#">Seo</a>
    </div>
    <div class="menu_item">
      <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thx for pointing this out :) It was also fixed by adding height:70px; to the .menu_item declaration. Happy new year!